# Hiding pixels inside a Shape

Tags: java, slick

I have a player wich is a png image and I want a part of him to be able to go behind things, so I need to know how to hide pixels that are inside of a shape

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way you do it. Simply draw the things that are on top last, they will overwrite the things below them. Or you can access the depth values and order the objects with that value.